# File format to store certain configurations

Tags: file, file-io

I would like to know which file format i can use to store(and easily parse and read) certain configuration items and their values. On eoption is INI file. Is there any other option like .opt file?

EDIT:
I am using C language.

Answer (score 0):

Look into XML.  It's got implementations in  many languages and is pretty easy to parse and create.

But a lot of it has to do with what language you're using.

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like to use XML files for configuration options.  Most non-power users can understand them relatively easy enough and there are many libraries out there that make them super easy to parse.